# How do I make a 'statistic over all played ' yahtzy games in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Scenario:** Every week, my siblings and I play a few games of Yahtzy (and some other stuff) - it's a nice ritual we have. Over time we've wondered about the statistics of all our games, like "how many times have we each rolled a Yahtzy?" and "What do we get on average?". The results we would like to see is f.ex 
"Adam, your average score is 243 and you get a yahtzy on 57% of all games".

*Optional Game Description: `Yahtzy` is a game where you roll five dice for categories like "2 Pair" and "Yahtzy", where getting a Yahtzy is rolling five of a kind, and is rewarded with 50 points. All sums are then added up at the end, and the one with highest total is the winner.*

**Main problem:** Iterating over all games.

**Idea:** 
Sheet `GAME` is the standard `yahtzy` entry for the game, where you record the scores. (also, see picture)

```
    Mike    Adam
1's:    1   3
2's:    8   6
3's:    9   9
2 Pair: 22  18
Yahtzy: 50  50
```

Sheet `ARCHIVE` is a a record of all games played.

```
DATE    MIKE_WIN    ADAM_WIN    MIKE_TOTAL  ADAM_TOTAL  MIKE_YAHTZY ADAM_YAHZY
07-07-20    TRUE    FALSE   303 238 TRUE    FALSE
12-07-20    FALSE   TRUE    220 268 FALSE   FALSE
```

Sheet `STATS` is a summary of relevant stats:

```
PLAYER  MIKE    ADAM
WINS    24  21
AVG SCORE   235 262
YAHTZY %    34% 54%
```

**Question 1 ?**: Is there a formula / function / macro that adds a row to ARCHIVE when each game is completed, and then clears GAME for the next game? (I can handle STATS myself, if ARCHIVE is working)

**Question 2 ?**: I add a copy of sheet GAME for each game played. Is there a formula / function / script that can loop through all sheets and either

- add them to `ARCHIVE` as described above, or
- lets me crunch the numbers directly in STATS ? Like:

  `MIKE AVG SCORE: =AVERAGE(EVERY_SHEET_CALLED_GAME!B7)`

If you can think of a solution, please help me out. It would be EVEN BETTER if there was no `VBA` involved so I could run this on my Android smartphone.

Thanks for your time!
// CHR

*PS: Assume the players are the same every time.*
[image: Example of a finished game in sheet GAME]

Comment: You should look at averageif() and averageifs(), with averageifs you can then define the person and perhaps a range of dates.

Comment: @SolarMike I can't see how this would help me extract diverse game statistics from more than 100 games. Do you have an example that would clear this up for me? Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

So I used countifs() based on simple data:

[image]

There are several functions available such as averageifs(), sumifs(), maxifs(), minifs()

Comment: I don't think this is the solution I was hoping for, but I appreciate you taking the effort to educate me :) I will look into those formulas a bit more!